# Question about implicit operator overloading in c#

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

```
MyClass c = 10;
```

Is there any way to make this code work? I know that through the implicit operator overloading you can get the opposite to work:

```
int i = instanceOfMyClass;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure...

```
class MyClass
{
    public static implicit operator MyClass(int value) { /* your code */ }
}
```