# Do types that support relational operators derive from a specific interface?

Tags: c#, .net, types, operators

I have a feeling the answer is no after reading through documentation. However, I am trying to find out whether it's possible to know if a type supports relational operators, such as: <, >, >= etc...

I am looking to do something like:

```
Func<MyObject, object> greaterThan = obj => obj > 10;
var results = myList.Where(greaterThan).ToList();
```

As I may be searching on different properties, it might be decimal, int or float. I am doing this in an MVC action so, as far as I know, it can't support generics. I can obviously move it out and have a generic implementation, but I'd like to know this answer first.

To elaborate, implicit operator overloading isn't feasible. The reason being is that property is not known until runtime (sorry should of mentioned that). Consequently nor can generics be used. Given any property, I need to check that it's not 0. This is a somewhat contrived example of my current implementation that seems to be working (not fully tested):

```
Func<MyObject, IComparable> prop = obj =>  isOn ? obj.DecimalVal : obj.IntValue;
Func<MyObject, bool> clause = obj => prop(obj).CompareTo(0) != 0;
var results = myList.Where(clause);
```

I'm just hoping that CompareTo will return 0; even if the prop evaluates a decimal which has a value of 0, when compared to the int 0 - despite these being different types.

**UPDATE**

I clearly had my hopes set too high, the above approach failed. Therefore, the solution I am using for now is not desirable but it's working. I would love to hear a more elegant approach.

```
Func<MyObject, dynamic> prop = obj =>  isOn ? obj.DecimalVal : obj.IntValue;
Func<MyObject, bool> clause = obj => prop(obj) != 0;
var results = myList.Where(clause);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `IComparable.CompareTo()` to check for equality. `IEquatable.Equals()` is the right method for that.

Comment: I can't use IEquatable as it is a generic implementation. Unless you mean changing the signature to `Func<MyObject, object> prop = ...` and using .Equals instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In C#, operators are static members of the types, so they can't be part of an interface.

There is one way for your code to work in C# 4: `dynamic`:

```
Func<dynamic, bool> greaterThan = obj => obj > 10;
var results = myList.Cast<dynamic>().Where(greaterThan).ToList();
```

This will work whether `myList` is a collection of `int`s, `double`s or `decimal`s. (But beware, `results` is of type `List<dynamic>`.)

But .Net actally provides some interfaces that can be used for the same purposes operators are commonly used for: comparing for equality (`IEquatable<T>`) and comparing for which element is greater and which is smaller (`IComparable<T>`). With those, you can write code like this:

```
static IEnumerable<T> GreaterThan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, T item)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return collection.Where(x => x.CompareTo(item) > 0);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the dynamic, this didn't cross my mind. Nor did the fact that the operators are static members!

Comment: +1 for dynamic and for a better explanation of the usage of IEquatable<T> and IComparable<T>

Answer (score 2):

What about using `IComparable<T>` `IEqutable<T>` interfaces. They are designed to perform generic comparison between objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [implicit operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542819/question-about-implicit-operator-overloading-in-c) here.  I would also consider @gmamaladze's answer about using IEquatable for implementing equality and IComparable for comparisons for sorting, though, too.

Comment: Could you clarify how is using conversion operators going to help here?

Answer (score 0):

No they don't. To support operators like `< > >= <=` you define the operators on your class explicitly. [Operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

You can also define [implicit casts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in your classes. This will allow you to implicitly cast your object to the target type, and then do math operations. [This article](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/07/operator-overloading-with-implicit-and.html) seems like it could be helpful to you.